# Generic enum converter to array list for Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

gender.ts

```
export enum Gender {
  Male = 1,
  Female = 2
}

export let genderDescriptions: { [P in keyof typeof Gender]: string } = {
  Female: "FemaleDescriptionExample",
  Male: "MaleDescriptionExample"
}
```

selectitem.ts

```
export interface SelectItem {
  label?: string;
  value: any;
}
```

my-component.ts

```
var myList: SelectItem[] = (Object.keys(Gender) as Array<keyof typeof Gender>)
  .filter(p => typeof Gender[p] === "number")
  .map(p => ({
    label: genderDescriptions[p],
    value: Gender[p]
  }));

console.log(myList);
```

Hi. I have a gender enum and i am mapping to SelectItem array. Console give me a result like below. It is working perfectly. But i want global enumConverter. So i wrote like below but this is not working. How can i do this as generic?

```
1: {label: "MaleDescriptionExample", value: 1}
2: {label: "FemaleDescriptionExample", value: 2}
```

I gave generic parameter T and description but everywhere gave error:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

```
  enumToSelectItemArray<T,Description>() {
   return (Object.keys(T) as Array<keyof typeof T>)
      .filter(p => typeof T[p] === "number" && T[p] !== 3)
      .map(p => ({
        label: descriptin[p],
        value: T[p]
      }))
  }
```

Comment: Please, include the error in the post.

Comment: The error is "'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here" @R.Richards

Comment: `Object.keys` expects an object, not a type.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's answer is what i was looking for. That code solved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type parameters are erased at runtime in typescript so you can't access any values at runtime through them. You will need parameters to pass in the enum and the descriptions object. We will use a generic type parameter to make the relation between the enum object and the descriptions object clear to the compiler.

```
enum Gender {
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

let genderDescriptions: Record<keyof typeof Gender, string> = {
    Female: "FemaleDescriptionExample",
    Male: "MaleDescriptionExample"
}

function enumToSelectItemArray<TEnum>(enumObj: TEnum, descriptions: Record<keyof TEnum, string>)
{
    return (Object.keys(enumObj) as Array<keyof TEnum>)
        .filter(p => typeof enumObj[p] === "number")
        .map(p => ({
            label: descriptions[p],
            value: enumObj[p]
        }));
}

console.log(enumToSelectItemArray(Gender, genderDescriptions));
```

**Note** Replaced the mapped type with `Record` they do the same thing (they are really the same thing) and record looks nicer, forgot about it in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Your code id working perfectly. You saved my a lot of time.